# C compiler cannot create executables when installing sage

Tags: macos, gcc, sage

I'm trying to make sage in my mac 10.9.5 and after I type make I have the error C compiler cannot create executables

Do you know why ? Xcode and command line tool are installed ...

I must admit that I am a bit lost when looking at the file above. Can anyone help me ?

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Sage configure 6.6.rc3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = dhcp-147-65-172-203.impa.br
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.4.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 171 tasks, 1002 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 3.67, Mach factor: 1.35
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Applications/sage/src/bin
PATH: /Applications/sage/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: //anaconda/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Users/samuelguerin/usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin
PATH: /usr/texbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2354: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2422: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2433: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2488: result: yes
configure:2639: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2678: result: config/install-sh -c -d
configure:2685: checking for gawk
configure:2715: result: no
configure:2685: checking for mawk
configure:2715: result: no
configure:2685: checking for nawk
configure:2715: result: no
configure:2685: checking for awk
configure:2701: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2712: result: awk
configure:2723: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2745: result: yes
configure:2774: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2791: result: yes
configure:2919: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2928: result: yes
configure:2945: checking for root user
configure:2954: result: no
configure:2994: checking build system type
configure:3008: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
configure:3028: checking host system type
configure:3041: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
configure:3172: checking for ar
configure:3188: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:3200: result: yes
configure:3221: checking for m4
configure:3237: found /usr/bin/m4
configure:3249: result: yes
configure:3270: checking for ranlib
configure:3286: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:3298: result: yes
configure:3319: checking for strip
configure:3335: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:3347: result: yes
configure:3367: checking for GNU or BSD tar
configure:3415: result: /usr/bin/tar
configure:3482: checking for latex
configure:3498: found /usr/texbin/latex
configure:3510: result: yes
configure:3534: checking for perl
configure:3552: found /usr/bin/perl
configure:3564: result: /usr/bin/perl
configure:3572: checking for Perl version 5.8.0 or later
configure:3583: result: yes
configure:3599: checking for dpkg
configure:3627: result: no
configure:3637: checking for dpkg-architecture
configure:3665: result: no
configure:3744: checking for gcc
configure:3771: result: gcc
configure:4000: checking for C compiler version
configure:4009: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4020: $? = 0
configure:4009: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/Applications/sage/local/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Applications/sage/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Configured with: ../src/configure --prefix=/Users/karl.crisman/Downloads/sage-6.6/local --with-local-prefix=/Users/karl.crisman/Downloads/sage-6.6/local --with-gmp=/Users/karl.crisman/Downloads/sage-6.6/local --with-mpfr=/Users/karl.crisman/Downloads/sage-6.6/local --with-mpc=/Users/karl.crisman/Downloads/sage-6.6/local --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libitm --without-isl --without-cloog  
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
configure:4020: $? = 0
configure:4009: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4020: $? = 1
configure:4009: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4020: $? = 1
configure:4040: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4062: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
sh: line 1:  1471 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find as 2> /dev/null
as: error: unable to find utility "as", not a developer tool or in PATH
configure:4066: $? = 1
configure:4104: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Sage"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sage"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "6.6.rc3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Sage 6.6.rc3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "sage-devel@googlegroups.com"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "sage"
| #define VERSION "6.6.rc3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4109: error: in `/Applications/sage':
configure:4111: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=
ac_cv_env_FC_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
ac_cv_path_PERL=/usr/bin/perl
ac_cv_path_TAR=/usr/bin/tar
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_found_ar=yes
ac_cv_prog_found_dpkg=no
ac_cv_prog_found_dpkg_arch=no
ac_cv_prog_found_latex=yes
ac_cv_prog_found_m4=yes
ac_cv_prog_found_ranlib=yes
ac_cv_prog_found_strip=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
ax_cv_prog_perl_version=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/missing aclocal-1.14'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='awk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP='cpp'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FC='gfortran'
FCFLAGS=''
GCC_VERSION=''
GREP=''
GXX_VERSION=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/missing makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='config/install-sh -c -d'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='sage'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='sage-devel@googlegroups.com'
PACKAGE_NAME='Sage'
PACKAGE_STRING='Sage 6.6.rc3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='sage'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='6.6.rc3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL='/usr/bin/perl'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='6.6.rc3'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_FC=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin13.4.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
found_ar='yes'
found_dpkg='no'
found_dpkg_arch='no'
found_latex='yes'
found_m4='yes'
found_ranlib='yes'
found_strip='yes'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin13.4.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /Applications/sage/config/install-sh'
libdir='/Applications/sage/local/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Sage"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sage"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "6.6.rc3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Sage 6.6.rc3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "sage-devel@googlegroups.com"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "sage"
#define VERSION "6.6.rc3"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: The key part seems to be: `configure:4062: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
sh: line 1:  1471 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find as 2> /dev/null
as: error: unable to find utility "as", not a developer tool or in PATH
configure:4066: $? = 1`.  It appears you don't have the command line tools installed, or you can't assemble code with the assembler.

Comment: I have downloaded it and it is installed. I made the thing in the preference of xcode and i have typed `xcode-select --install`. How should I check that my assemble works fine or not ? Thanks for your answer by the way

Comment: Create a 'hello world' program in C and check that you can compile it OK.  You could just about get away with `int main(void){puts("Hello world!"); return 0; }` -- you should prefix that with `#include <stdio.h>` on a line on its own.  Save it in `hello.c`; compile it: `gcc hello.c` and then (if there are no compilation errors), run it: `./a.out`.  You should see a well-known message.  If that fails, then we have an installation problem for GCC.

Comment: If the 'hello world' test works OK, we may have to delve into what these lines in your output mean:  `configure:4009: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/Applications/sage/local/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Applications/sage/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Configured with: ../src/configure ... --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libitm --without-isl --without-cloog  
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) `.  It appears that this is not using XCode.

Comment: Hello World !
Yeah it is printing Hello world.

Comment: OK; that seems to rule out one line of enquiry.  AFAIK, that wouldn't work if the assembler were not installed or was dysfunctional.  When you run `gcc -v` at the command line, do you see the same information as is output in the config script output?  (Note that the config in the output contains a user name that I'd not expect to be there in the Apple-supplied GCC.)  Is the correct version of GCC being used by the configuration script?

Comment: I think it's different,
I have `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix` It's seems that the version here is 4.2.1 ...

Comment: Run your configure process with `./configure CC=/usr/bin/gcc` and see whether that works better.

Comment: OK. Does the error message change at all?  Do you see the system GCC in the log or is it still the other one?

Comment: Ha sorry, I'm not very helpful :) No it's exactly the same

Comment: OK; so the configure script is ignoring our requests to use a different compiler. That's not helpful, especially since the compiler it is choosing to use doesn't work. I downloaded and extracted Sage 6.7 source to my Mac. Is there a reason you want to use 6.6.rc3 instead of 6.7? I then ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME/oss/sage` (which is where I'd want it installed). It correctly picked up my GCC 5.1.0 installation (home-built). The compilation is working so far. I suggest: (1) Download 6.7 (or 6.6 released) code and built that, or (2) remove your build directory and re-extract from the start.

Comment: The compilation has not been wholly trouble free.  I've run the `make` process three times so far.  There's an environment variable that I set to preserve previous build efforts, and I ran `make -k -j4` to do the build.  It takes a while -- it is a pretty big system (450 MiB compressed source).  GCC 5.1.0 has some default warnings which are irksome (it compiles in C11 mode -- strictly GNU11 mode -- by default) when dealing with a code base not attuned to it.

Comment: OK; after a bit over an hour, I'm giving up for the time being.  The configuration process worked; the builds of r-3.2.0.p0, setuptools-12.4, singular-3.1.7p1.p0, sympy-0.7.6 failed.  I'm not sure if some of those are consequences of the `-k` option, but probably not.  I think it was setuptools-12.4 that failed the first time around.

Comment: @Bleuderk: You seem to be building Sage 6.6.rc3... why not build Sage 6.7 or Sage 6.8.beta3, which are more recent? Also, any reason not to install OS X 10.10?

Comment: Did you download a Mac OS binary distribution of Sage, rather than the source code?

Comment: Yeah I think I'm gonna reboot everything on my computer, it's quite a mess. I have installed some thing at a wrong place I think. Do you a have a good website with advices about how to keep a mac clean from the inside ? Thanks for your help !